# In the SIKE known answer tests, why is there only one secret key?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography

I'm looking at the [SIKE known answer tests](https://github.com/microsoft/PQCrypto-SIKE/blob/master/KAT/PQCkemKAT_434.rsp) and am realizing that I'm confused on all the different terms in a Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

From the Wikipedia page, I would think there would be a public key and 2 secret keys, then a shared secret. However, the KAT provides a public key, a secret key, a shared secret, and a ciphertext. What exactly is the ciphertext, and where is the secret key?

Answer (score 3):

[This Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange) describes SIDH, a key exchange protocol.

SIKE is a [key encapsulation mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation), like all entries in the NIST PQ competition, it has a different API.